# How do I get access to my outer variable from a predefined callback I pass in?

Tags: javascript, sorting, scope, callback, compare

So I have this code which just sorts a product list by price or anything the user wants and it works:

```
var sortProductsBy = function(products, sortType){
  //sort type is a string, it could be 'price'
  products.sort(function (product1, product2) {

    var product1AttrValue  = parseInt( $(product1).attr(sortType).replace('$','') );
    var product2AttrValue  = parseInt( $(product2).attr(sortType).replace('$','') );

    if (product1AttrValue < product2AttrValue ) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (product1AttrValue > product2AttrValue) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;// product1 must be equal to product2
  })
};
```

The sort functions callback which I'm defining as an argument to my sort function is quite long so I wanted to decouple it, define it elsewhere, and the pass in my sort function like so:

```
var sortProductsBy = function(products, sortType){
  //I need compareFunc to somehow have access to sortType
    products.sort(compareFunc)
}
```

I need my compareFunc to somehow have access to sortType variable that get's passed in, but due to scope I want have access to it. Is there a way I could somehow gain access to it without having to define my entire callback like in the first code snippet?

Comment: Doing `$(product1)` is an expensive operation that you would likely want to minimize.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `function compareFunc (sortType, a, b) {}`:

```
var sortProductsBy = function (products, sortType) {
  products.sort(compareFunc.bind(null, sortType));
}
```

See: [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score -1):

Calling `compareFunc` from the callback would work.

```
function compareFunc(sortType) {
  // use sortType
}

var sortProductsBy = function(products, sortType){
  //I need compareFunc to somehow have access to sortType
  products.sort(function() {
    compareFunc(sortType);
  });
}
```

Also, have a look at the JavaScript functions `bind()` and `call()` and experiment with how you might use those, for fun.